# How to disable ( ignore ) stock at checkout - Bigcommerce

Tags: checkout, bigcommerce, stock

We run a b2b store with average carts being built over a period of 12-25 days. In This time the same prodcuts will be added and stay sitting in multiple carts, then will be ordered by some of those customers and checked out before other customers who also added it can. This leads to them having 10-30+ items that need to be removed one by one. Looking for ideas or a developer interested in working with us to basically ignore stock once it is in the cart to they can simply checkout and we adapt the PO post order. But still keep stock live sitewide so we can midgate out of stockitems that can be purchased.

Answer (score 1):

Since cart/checkout functionality is implemented as part of BigCommerce platform, I'm afraid there isn't much that can be done to allow checkout with items in cart that are out of stock, providing the stock for those products is managed: you either have managed stock or you don't.

After all, preventing customers from purchasing out of stock products, creating orders that can't be fulfilled, is the very purpose of stock management...

That said, there may be a workaround, as baskets can be reworked, once created and left inactive for a while, using webhooks and BigCommerce Cart API (server to server calls). You could have two versions of the same product (using, for example a naming convention as "SKUX" for stock-managed, publicly available product, and "SKUX-NS" for "No-Stock" unmanaged stock version of the same product, not publicly available).

When a basket is old enough (e.g. next day), the server automation could use the BigCommerce Cart API to remove each "old" stock managed cart item "SKUX" and add back to the same cart the equivalent "SKUX-NS" version of that product, which - being a stock-unmanaged product - will not cause stock errors in checkout.